# If you do really well on a reasoning test, is it very likely that you will be given an interview?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process

It was actually a logic test at guessing the next pattern.

Comment: very well? As in 100%, 99%?

Comment: Depends how they weight the test amongst other things they're assessing you on - it may not be enough to save you if you do poorly on other factors. I don't think we can possibly say in the general case.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily.

A logic/reasoning test is simply one factor of many that will be scored and used to help the recruiter/HR/hiring manager make a decision.

You may get 100% in the reasoning test, but if your CV doesn't meet the needs of one of the chains in the hiring pathway, or other candidates are better, or any number of other reasons then you may still be dropped from the list of candidates.